# Why does SBT look for pom instead of ivy.xml

Tags: maven, sbt, ivy

So i have a build.sbt that looks like this ,
This is a part of it .

```
resolvers ++= Seq(
                  "Typesafe Repository"               at "http://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/releases/",
                  "SpringSource Milestone Repository" at "http://repo.spring.io/libs-milestone-local",
                  "Artifactory Repository"    at "http://artifactory.x.y.com:8080/artifactory/xyz/" 
)



libraryDependencies ++= Seq(
                       "com.typesafe.akka"          % "akka-actor_2.11"                         % akkaActorAPIVersion,
                       "org.scalaz"                 % "scalaz-core_2.11"                        % scalazCoreVersion,
                       "org.scalactic"              % "scalactic_2.11"                          % scalacticVersion ,
                       "org.springframework"        % "spring-context"                          % springLibraryVersion,
                       "org.springframework"        % "spring-beans"                            % springLibraryVersion,
                       "org.springframework"        % "spring-core"                             % springLibraryVersion,
                       "org.springframework"        % "spring-context"                          % springLibraryVersion,
                       "org.springframework"        % "spring-web"                              % springLibraryVersion,


                       "com.tom.som.xyz"    % "xyz-abc"                               % Version, 
                       "com.tom.som.xyz"    % "xyz-def"                                % Version,

                       "org.scalatest"              % "scalatest_2.11"                          % scalaTestVersion  % "test",
                       "org.scalamock"              % "scalamock-scalatest-support_2.11"        % scalaMockVersion  % "test",
                       "junit"                      % "junit"                                   % junitVersion      % "test"
    )
```

Now the `xyz-abc` and `xyz-def` libraries are on the artifactory repo at `http://artifactory.x.y.com:8080/artifactory/xyz/`.

But these two are not being downloaded like the other jars.
Now i saw at the repo path the individual libraries have a `ivy-version.xml` file.
But when the build runs i see it looks for a `xyz-abc-version.pom` file which does not exist !

I cannot figure out why this is happening. Please help.